# Can you create a reusable survey question in Ansible Tower?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Creating surveys is pretty straightforward, as is using their results in templates/jobs. However, I am finding that I have a survey that I keep having to recreate. Is it possible to create one that could then be re-used across multiple templates?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is that you could use the controller/tower/awx collection, and from that the job_template module, which has a survey_spec option.
In other words: you could create a playbook/job template, that updates/creates other job templates and adds the survey.

Here the module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/job_template_module.html#ansible-collections-awx-awx-job-template-module

...and here's how to define the survey_spec: https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/controllerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_survey_spec_list

With this you practically automate your tower/controller/awx config.